# Converting a multivariate quartic expression to a quadratic one

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm stuck on a problem in Boyd's optimization book. I need a hint on how to convert the following quartic function into a quadratic one. I've gone as far as expanding the whole thing into a big summation comprised of terms of the form $x^Tx, ~ a_i^Tx$, etc. but haven't got anywhere from there. I want to know if my approach is correct at all.

$f(x)=\sum_i ~(\|x-a_i\|^2 - r^2)^2$

where $r\in R$ and $x,a_i\in R^n$.

Here's what I've done so far.

$f(x)=g(x)^Tg(x)$ where 
$g(x)=\begin{bmatrix}
    (x-a_1)^T(x-a_1)\\
    \vdots \\
    (x-a_n)^T(x-a_n)
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}
    r^2\\
    \vdots \\
    r^2
\end{bmatrix}.$

Edit: Something just came to my mind. If I can prove that $R\leq \| x\|^2$ at the optimal $x$ for $R= \| x\|^2-r$, then I can linearize the terms $\|x-a_i\|^2 - r^2$ by introducing the variable $R$. Anyone has an idea how I can prove $R\leq \| x\|^2$?

Comment: How about adding a new set of variables $y_i$ and the conditions that $y_i = \lVert x-a_i \rVert^2$?

Comment: I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: I think by quadratic, they mean $x^TQx+g^Tx+c$. I don't know how to getthe Q for example!

Comment: Maybe this helps: Let $y_i = \|x-a_i\| - r$ and  $z_i = \|x-a_i\| + r$ and add these constraints to your model. Then your function can be written as  $\sum_i (y_i\,z_i)^2$.

Comment: I've thought of doing that but it leads to the same problem. How do I extract Q from there?

Comment: I guess I could write it as $t_i^T I t_i$ where $t_i=y_iz_i$.